# servlet-context.xml not mapping resources as directed mvc:resources

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a `AJAX` Template that I have downloaded from `themeforest`. I want to keep the Template folder structure as it is, so that I can do updates and patches easily.

My folder structure is

```
  - WebContent
     servlet-context.xml
     - WEB-INF\
         web.xml
         - Template\
           css\
           img\
        - views\
          index.html
```

My web.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>MyAuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>MyMnoxWebContextListner</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

My servlet-context.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />  
    <mvc:resources mapping="img/**" location="/WEB-INF/Template/img/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="css/**" location="/WEB-INF/Template/css/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="js/**" location="/WEB-INF/Template/js//" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->    
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />     
    <!-- <mvc:resources mapping="**" location="/WEB-INF/views/" />
 -->    
    <bean           class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    </bean>

    <!-- <bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy"> 
        properties </bean> -->

    <!-- <context:component-scan base-package="net.codejava.spring" /> -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="Mycontrollers" />

</beans>
```

My login.html contains

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/some.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/somemore.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/alotmore.css">
```

In the servlet-context.xml if I comment

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
```

I get

```
I get HTTP Status 404 -
type Status report
message
description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/8.0.41
```

If I uncomment the line, the `login.html` opens up, but then the path's (`img/`, `css/`)within the `login.html` are not mapped.

Which also means that servlet-context.xml is being read. The console prints

```
2018-01-02 12:35:58 INFO  SimpleUrlHandlerMapping:315 - Mapped URL path [/img/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
2018-01-02 12:35:58 INFO  SimpleUrlHandlerMapping:315 - Mapped URL path [/css/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#1'
2018-01-02 12:35:58 INFO  SimpleUrlHandlerMapping:315 - Mapped URL path [/js/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#2'
```

I have read thru many SO questions, and have reached a dead end.

Note : Once I get some answers, I'll make the question lighter and remove unnecessary xml content.

Comment: Try using `<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/WEB-INF/Template/css/**" />`

Comment: Just tried it, did not work.

Comment: Then try using absolute path i.e: including context path. e.g `href="http://server:port/context/css/some.css"`.

Comment: I know that will `work`. But the need is to keep the design right and avoid rework. You are advising me to use absolute path instead of getting relative path working. Meaning that once I fix this I cant change the path. Horrible code design.

Comment: Your `css`,`js` and `img` folder should be under `resource` folder and that `resource` folder should be mapped to mvc resources.Your folder structure is horrible also.

Comment: templates come like this, i am wondering if there is a way to achieve this without the "resources" folder change thing..